# Get a value from SOAP response from multiple xml data using PHP

Tags: php, xml, soap

This is the response of the soap request.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <GetConfigurationInfoResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://micros-hosting.com/EGateway/">
            <configInfoResponse>
                <OperationalResult>
                    <Success>true</Success>
                    <ErrorCode>Success</ErrorCode>
                    <ErrorMessage>Success</ErrorMessage>
                </OperationalResult>
                <ConfigInfoType>
                    <EConfigurationInfoType>MENUITEMDEFINITIONS</EConfigurationInfoType>
                </ConfigInfoType>
                **<MenuItemDefinitions>&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?&gt;&lt;?micros-type Micros.PosCore.DataStore.DbRecords.DbMenuItemDefinition[], PosCore, Version=2.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null?&gt;&lt;ArrayOfDbMenuItemDefinition xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"&gt;&lt;DbMenuItemDefinition&gt;&lt;NameOptions&gt;0000000&lt;/NameOptions&gt;&lt;MenuItemDefID&gt;4055&lt;/MenuItemDefID&gt;&lt;HierStrucID&gt;25&lt;/HierStrucID&gt;&lt;MenuItemMasterID&gt;1570&lt;/MenuItemMasterID&gt;&lt;SequenceNum&gt;1&lt;/SequenceNum&gt;&lt;Name1&gt;&lt;StringNumberId&gt;8507&lt;/StringNumberId&gt;&lt;StringText&gt;=Breakfast=&lt;/StringText&gt;&lt;/Name1&gt;&lt;Name2&gt;&lt;StringNumberId&gt;8508&lt;/StringNumberId&gt;&lt;StringText /&gt;&lt;/Name2&gt;&lt;SluSort&gt;0&lt;/SluSort&gt;&lt;NluNumber&gt;0&lt;/NluNumber&gt;&lt;Tare&gt;0&lt;/Tare&gt;&lt;Surcharge&gt;0&lt;/Surcharge&gt;&lt;IconNumber&gt;0&lt;/IconNumber&gt;&lt;OptionBits&gt;00000000&lt;/OptionBits&gt;&lt;SpecialCount&gt;0&lt;/SpecialCount&gt;&lt;PrepTime&gt;0&lt;/PrepTime&gt;&lt;Name3&gt;&lt;StringNumberId&gt;0&lt;/StringNumberId&gt;&lt;StringText /&gt;&lt;/Name3&gt;&lt;LongDescriptor&gt;&lt;StringNumberId&gt;0&lt;/StringNumberId&gt;&lt;StringText /&gt;&lt;/LongDescriptor&gt;&lt;MenuItemClassObjNum&gt;0&lt;/MenuItemClassObjNum&gt;&lt;NluGroupIndex&gt;0&lt;/NluGroupIndex&gt;&lt;SluIndex&gt;0&lt;/SluIndex&gt;&lt;HhtSluIndex&gt;0&lt;/HhtSluIndex&gt;&lt;MainLevels&gt;00000000&lt;/MainLevels&gt;&lt;SubLevels&gt;00000000&lt;/SubLevels&gt;&lt;PosRef&gt;0&lt;/PosRef&gt;&lt;PrintClassObjNum&gt;0&lt;/PrintClassObjNum&gt;&lt;PrefixLevelOverride&gt;0&lt;/PrefixLevelOverride&gt;&lt;GuestCount&gt;0&lt;/GuestCount&gt;&lt;MenuLevelEntries /&gt;&lt;DefaultCondiments /&gt;&lt;NextScreen /&gt;&lt;MiMasterObjNum&gt;10010000&lt;/MiMasterObjNum&gt;&lt;CheckAvailability&gt;false&lt;/CheckAvailability&gt;&lt;OutOfMenuItem&gt;false&lt;/OutOfMenuItem&gt;&lt;/DbMenuItemDefinition&gt;&lt;DbMenuItemDefinition;&lt;/ArrayOfDbMenuItemDefinition&gt;</MenuItemDefinitions>**
                </configInfoResponse>
        </GetConfigurationInfoResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

How can I get value from this `<MenuItemDefinitions></MenuItemDefinitions>`? This xml element inside another XML data. How to say this kind of XML?

How to filter that value using PHP? I only need get value from the inside `<MenuItemDefinitions></MenuItemDefinitions>` xml value.

This is the soap request php code.

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://192.168.5.10:8080/EGateway/SimphonyPosApiWeb.asmx");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetConfigurationInfo>
      <vendorCode />
      <employeeObjectNum>10009</employeeObjectNum>
      <configurationInfoType>
        <int>1</int>
      </configurationInfoType>
      <revenueCenter>5</revenueCenter>
      <configInfoResponse />
    </GetConfigurationInfo>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  "Content-Type: text/xml;",
  "SOAPAction: http://192.168.5.10:8080/EGateway/GetConfigurationInfo"
));

$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

var_dump($response);
```

Comment: Whats your problem, digging out the contents of `<MenuItemDefinitions>` or realising it too is an XML Document and therefore needs to be treated as such

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thank you for your reply. My problem is I need to converted this  <MenuItemDefinitions> response to xml and get value from the that xml. This <MenuItemDefinitions> inside menu items name available, I need to get that value.

Comment: So show the code that reads this XMLDoc please

Comment: Please, put all this into the question using the EDIT link under the question, nobody can read code in a comment

Comment: @RiggsFolly I already edit the question.

Comment: @RiggsFolly How to get that value?